# OfficeOpenXml.LicenseException

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Estoy creando un documento Excel, pero al llegar a esta linea me marca este error:

```
Please set the ExcelPackage.LicenseContext property. See https://epplussoftware.com/developers/licenseexception
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: OfficeOpenXml.LicenseException: Please set the ExcelPackage.LicenseContext property. See https://epplussoftware.com/developers/licenseexception

Error de código fuente:

Línea 638:ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 9):

Necesitas agregar el contexto de la licencia (en las versiones más nuevas de EPPlus se volvió de paga).

Si el contexto de tu aplicación es un desarrollo no comercial, puedes utilizar:

```
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
```

antes de hacer el llamado a:

```
 ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
```